# Database not only local machine but available to anyone?

Tags: database

I need some advice regarding which database I should use.

I want to create a web application in Java EE and I need a database for storing some information.

I want to make it available not only from my personal computer. The Java code will be simple exported, but what should I do regarding the database?

Which database should I use in order to make it available to anyone?

Comment: Database in the clould? Amazon RDS - http://aws.amazon.com/rds/

Comment: Your personal computer is going to be the database server?

Comment: yes, my personal computer is going to be the database server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just about any modern, client/server dbms will work. If I were in your shoes, I'd try [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/) first. The online docs have a full chapter on [server configuration](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config.html).  Pay particular attention to "[Connections and authentication](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-connection.html)".

Often a remote user will connect to an application (a web page, for example), and that application will connect to the database. Usually the application and the dbms run on different servers, in which case the dbms will accept connections only from localhost (for maintenance), the local area network (for company internal use), and from the application server.

Do some research before you decide to let the dbms accept connections from every IP address on Earth; that's a little risky.